# What is the safest way to convert long integer into array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, casting, reinterpret-cast

Right now I have this code:

```
uint64_t buffer = 0;
const uint8_t * data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&buffer);
```

And this works, but it seems risky due to the hanging pointer (and looks ugly too). I don't want naked pointers sitting around. I want to do something like this:

```
uint64_t buffer = 0;
const std::array<uint8_t, 8> data = partition_me_softly(buffer);
```

Is there and c++11 style construct that allows for me to get this into a safe container, preferable a `std::array` out of an `unsigned int` like this without inducing overhead?

If not, what would be the ideal way to improve this code to be more safe?

---

So I modified dauphic's answer to be a little more generic:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
std::array<T, sizeof(U) / sizeof(T)> ScalarToByteArray(const U v)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_integral<U>::value, 
        "Template parameter must be a scalar type");
    std::array<T, sizeof(U) / sizeof(T)> ret;
    std::copy((T*)&v, ((T*)&v) + sizeof(U), ret.begin());
    return ret;
}
```

This way you can use it with more types like so:

```
uint64_t buffer = 0;
ScalarToByteArray<uint8_t>(buffer);
```

Comment: No, and the answer depends on whether you care about preserving endian-ness. Aside from that, naked pointers are perfectly okay for this sort of thing, as long as you aren't storing them.

Comment: Yes I do care about endianness.

Comment: Your modified version fails when `sizeof(T) > sizeof(U)`(`sizeof(U) / sizeof(T) == 0`) and when `sizeof(T) != 1` (`((T*)&v) + sizeof(U)` becomes incorrect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to store an integer in a byte array, the best approach is probably to just cast the integer to a `uint8_t*` and copy it into an `std::array`. You're going to have to use raw pointers at some point, so your best option is to encapsulate the operation into a function.

```
template<typename T>
std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)> ScalarToByteArray(const T value)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, 
        "Template parameter must be a scalar type");
    std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)> result;
    std::copy((uint8_t*)&value, ((uint8_t*)&value) + sizeof(T), result.begin());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I added a modified version of your answer to my question that allows you to add the type of array to it. Cheers.

Comment: You may replace *C Cast* by `reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>`.

Comment: Warning: endianness is not managed. `hton*` family may be useful.

Comment: @Jarod42, by `hton*` family you mean [this](http://minix1.woodhull.com/manpages/man3/hton.3.html)?

Comment: @AdriC.S.: yes (but `include` may changes depending of platform).